# WinDbg: how to set a native breakpoint for .net program

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, windbg

Given a simple .NET program (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/platform-invoke-examples):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

class Sample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "TEST", "TEST", 0);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hwnd, String text, String title, uint type);
}
```

The program calls native Win32 function [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
I want to set a breakpoint on that native function in WinDbg. For API docs it follows that the function is in user32.dll so I'm using `bp` to set a breakpoint at `user32!MessageBox`.

I run WinDbg, File/Open Executable, open the program's exe, got into debugger. Then I executed `bp user32!MessageBoxW` but it said me: "bp expression 'user32!MessageBoxW' could not be resolved, adding deferred bp".

[image]

So if I continue with `g` I won't get into the breakpoint and get error:

"Breakpoint 0's offset expression evaluation failed.
Check for invalid symbols or bad syntax."

**UPDATE:**
see the accepted question - `user32!MessageBox` isn't correct, instead `user32!MessageBoxW` should be used. That message "bp expression 'user32!MessageBoxW' could not be resolved, adding deferred bp" is totally OK and just says that there're no symbols loaded yet.

[image]

Comment: use `user32!.MessageBoxW` or `user32!.MessageBoxA` - `user32!MessageBox` not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows API functions that have string parameters usually come in two versions, suffixed with `A` and `W`. The C/C++ SDK has defines that picks one or the other in the compilers preprocessor step.

In WinDbg you can type `bp user32!MessageBox` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the known symbols/exports but that only works once user32 has been loaded if you are using deferred symbol lookup.

If you don't want to deal with all that you can just set a breakpoint on both:

```
bp user32!MessageBoxA
bp user32!MessageBoxW
```

WinDbg will display something like this:

```
0:000> bp user32!MessageBoxA
Bp expression 'user32!MessageBoxA' could not be resolved, adding deferred bp
0:000> bp user32!MessageBoxW 
Bp expression 'user32!MessageBoxW' could not be resolved, adding deferred bp
0:000> g
ModLoad: 76d90000 76e3e000   C:\windows\SysWOW64\ADVAPI32.dll
...
ModLoad: 763a0000 764b6000   C:\windows\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
...    
ModLoad: 741d0000 74258000   C:\windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 72700000 7276e000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
Breakpoint 0 hit
...
USER32!MessageBoxA:
76405f69 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading question but I do tried to use W/A functions, please see the updated question

Comment: Oh, OK, that message "Bp expression 'user32!MessageBoxA' could not be resolved, adding deferred bp" seems legit and actually breakpoints hit. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you just start your application using Open Executable, user32 is not loaded yet.

```
0:000> lm
start    end        module name
00d80000 00d88000   MessageBoxWTest   (deferred)             
73750000 737a4000   MSCOREE    (deferred)             
764a0000 76570000   KERNEL32   (deferred)             
76690000 76867000   KERNELBASE   (deferred)             
77b70000 77cfd000   ntdll      (export symbols)       C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

So WinDBG won't be able to load and find symbols.
And here you have 2 options:

1. Use `bu` Break Unresolved (deferred breakpoint also uses it). In this case debugger is waiting for symbols with exactly that name you've specified to be loaded. If you've mistyped then breakpoint won't be hit. Like in your question.
2. Wait for particular module to load with `sxe ld name` command, then find symbol and set breakpoint.

_

```
0:000> sxe ld user32
0:000> g
ModLoad: 77030000 770a8000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 74720000 747dd000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 763e0000 76423000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 768f0000 769ae000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 74590000 745b0000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SspiCli.dll
ModLoad: 74580000 7458a000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 761b0000 76207000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcryptPrimitives.dll
ModLoad: 736d0000 7374d000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 76430000 76475000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 75e00000 76046000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\combase.dll
ModLoad: 77a50000 77b67000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 770b0000 770d2000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 76050000 761ae000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 76870000 768ec000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 770e0000 77255000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
eax=00000000 ebx=00800000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0337c030 edi=0337bf90
eip=77bdea0c esp=0113d424 ebp=0113d470 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xc:
77bdea0c c22800          ret     28h
```

Here, we stoppped right after USER32 was loaded. Now, WinDBG can load symbols for it and we can find them.

```
0:000> x user32!MessageBox*
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll - 
7714f8b0          USER32!MessageBoxA (<no parameter info>)
7714f8e0          USER32!MessageBoxExA (<no parameter info>)
7714f910          USER32!MessageBoxExW (<no parameter info>)
7714f940          USER32!MessageBoxIndirectA (<no parameter info>)
7714fa40          USER32!MessageBoxIndirectW (<no parameter info>)
7714faa0          USER32!MessageBoxTimeoutA (<no parameter info>)
7714fb50          USER32!MessageBoxTimeoutW (<no parameter info>)
7714fce0          USER32!MessageBoxW (<no parameter info>)
```

Then we can set a breakpoint that will be hit for sure.

```
0:000> bp USER32!MessageBoxA
0:000> bp USER32!MessageBoxW
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=7714f8b0 ebx=00000006 ecx=00000000 edx=00000004 esi=03023b48 edi=00d3f350
eip=7714f8b0 esp=00d3f26c ebp=00d3f320 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
USER32!MessageBoxA:
7714f8b0 8bff            mov     edi,edi
0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  7714f8b0     0001 (0001)  0:**** USER32!MessageBoxA
     1 e Disable Clear  7714fce0     0001 (0001)  0:**** USER32!MessageBoxW
```